# SQL Summing Columns Grouped By Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I'm very new to SQL and this has been stumping me for a while!

I'm starting off with a bunch of columns that I need to aggregate by playerID.

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
| playerID  |  AA        | BB            | CC     |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|      Adam | 5          | 2             |     10 |
|      Josh | 12         | 3             |     10 |
|       Sam | 8          | 5             |     15 |
|      Adam | 2          | 5             |     25 |
|       Sam | 4          | 4             |      5 |
|      Josh | 10         | 3             |      6 |
|       Adam| 4          | 2             |      7 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

Ideally, the end result would sum up AA, BB, and CC for each player and give something like

```
| playerID  |  AA        | BB            | CC     |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|      Adam | 11         | 9             |     42 |
|      Josh | 22         | 6             |     16 |
|       Sam | 12         | 9             |     20 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

I've managed to at least group records of the same name together by doing

```
SELECT playerID, COUNT(*) c FROM playertable GROUP BY playerID
```

But I'm not sure how to sum the records properly once they're grouped. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function.

```
SELECT playerID, 
       SUM(AA) AS AA, 
       SUM(BB) AS BB, 
       SUM(CC) AS CC
FROM playertable 
GROUP BY playerID
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bcc91/1)